# Scroll not working on Salesforce1 App

Tags: visualforce, mobilesdk

I have the basic Account tab in my Salesforce tenant, but when i open this tab in my Salesforce 1 mobile app, i am unable to scroll to view all the details.

Can anyone tell me how could i rectify this issue

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "basic Account tab" - is this a custom tab that displays some accounts, or are you referring to the Accounts under the Recent submenu?

Comment: So there is an Account Detail page, for every account. So when i open this account in a salesforce mobile app, i cannot scroll to view all the detail only few fields show up related to that account. Hope this clarifies

Comment: Which device and OS version is this on?  Is it the installed mobile application or the HTML5 version.

Comment: This was answered I suppose.

https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/25276/visualforce-page-will-not-scroll-on-salesforce1-app/37156#37156?newreg=f964b434f5214d84a7b8d24920c5115e