# Unable to scroll in visualforce page rendered in salesforce1 app

Tags: visualforce, force.com, salesforce1-app

I am having a visualforce page which is rendered inside salesforce1 app and I am unable to scroll the page.

does any one have any pointers for ficing the issue or anything that is restricting the page from scrolling inside salesforce1 app?

Comment: Here's what I found in else where:
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/25276/visualforce-page-will-not-scroll-on-salesforce1-app/37156#37156?newreg=f964b434f5214d84a7b8d24920c5115e