# Salesforce1 page scroll is stopped working suddently

Tags: salesforce1-app, scrolling

We are using visualforce pages with bootstrap and till yesterday it was working fine.

But from today scroll is not working.

If there is scrollable content(long verticle data) on page then on click page is blanking out.

If there is enough data for single screen then its working fine.

Please help as it may impact my delivery. Thanks

Comment: This previous question and answer may help http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/25276/visualforce-page-will-not-scroll-on-salesforce1-app?rq=1

Comment: TL;DR set `showHeader="false"`.

Comment: Thanks Andrian for reply. Appreciated. ButI am already using showHeader =false.

Comment: this is simple example i have created below code does not have any salesforce logic. Simple code for tab panel which you will be able to save on any Salesforce org. If you click on Menu1 and try to scroll you can see diffrence. Please create Quick action to test on salesforce1(IOS)

Comment: I am not able to add code because of charecter limit but please embed below code and test with large text of any tab http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_pills_dynamic&stacked=h